In a local repository, I want to make the changes in file but I don't want to commit or stash. Those are only for me, on that branch
In config/database.yml of the rails application, I want to add the username and password for the database as follows
Old
default: &default
  adapter:  postgresql
  pool: 20
  timeout: 5000

changed
default: &default
  adapter:  postgresql
  pool: 20
  timeout: 5000
*  username: postgres
  password: password*

above changes i dont want to push or commit simply I want to ignore
but if I put them in .gitignore file what will also need to commit
Note: I also want to switch the branches on the local
I tried to stash the changes
 git stash -m "added the username and password"

but as soon as pull
git pull 

changes got removed

Not sure exactly what you mean by "as soon as pull ... changes got removed"  The changes should have been removed when you ran stash, not when you ran pull.  The workflow is to stash your changes (so they are gone from your working directory), then you pull to update the repo, then you pop the stash to restore the changes to your working directory.

Note that making a stash creates a commit, so if you truly don't want to make a commit then you should not use stash.

You can use stash for this, but you should understand how it works.
git stash takes your currently staged changes and stashes them, removing the changes from your current git status.
git stash apply stash_id takes the stashed changed and applies them to your current worktree. git stash pop stash_id would do the same, but it also deletes the stash so it can never be applied again.
If you are done with the local testing and want to pull and then commit without the config changes, you can do it like this:

git add config/database.yml (stage the changes you want stashed)
git stash -m "your stash name" (or just git stash, but giving it a name makes it easier to navigate multiple stashes)
Now your changed configuration is no longer present, and you can git pull, git add and git commit whatever you need
When you are done, you can view the stashes with git stash list, find the reference to your stash (could be something like stash@{0}) and apply/pop the stash back via git stash apply stash@{0} to get your testing configuration back

